# ceph pg ID query hangs/ stuck/unclean PG

Tags: ceph

Ceph version: 0.94.1

```
ceph -s
    cluster 30266c5f-5e10-4027-936c-e4409667b409
 health HEALTH_WARN
        65 pgs stale
        22 pgs stuck inactive
        65 pgs stuck stale
        22 pgs stuck unclean
 monmap e7: 7 mons at {kvm1=10.136.8.129:6789/0,kvm2=10.136.8.130:6789/0,kvm3=10.136.8.131:6789/0,kvm4=10.136.8.132:6789/0,kvm5=10.136.8.133:6789/0,kvm6=10.136.8.134:6789/0,kvm7=10.136.8.135:6789/0}
        election epoch 122, quorum 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 kvm1,kvm2,kvm3,kvm4,kvm5,kvm6,kvm7
 osdmap e368: 14 osds: 14 up, 14 in
  pgmap v1072573: 1128 pgs, 8 pools, 186 GB data, 51533 objects
        630 GB used, 7330 GB / 8319 GB avail
            1041 active+clean
              65 stale+active+clean
              22 creating
```

client io 361 kB/s rd, 528 kB/s wr, 48 op/s

```
ceph osd stat 
osdmap e368: 14 osds: 14 up, 14 in
```

As you can see I have issues with stale/inactive/unclean.  I tried to do

```
ceph pg 0.21 query
```

And this hangs.  (0.21 is one of the stale pgs).  Strace shows this:

[pid  4850] futex(0x7f8cd8003984, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7f8cd8003980,

```
{FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1} <unfinished ...>
[pid  4855] <... sendmsg resumed> )     = 9
[pid  4850] <... futex resumed> )       = 1
[pid  4855] futex(0x7f8cd8026cd4, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 19, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  4841] <... futex resumed> )       = 0
[pid  4850] futex(0x7f8cd801e2ac, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 11, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  4841] futex(0x7f8cd8003900, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid  4841] futex(0x7f8cd8003984, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 39, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  4833] <... select resumed> )      = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  4833] select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 4000}) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  4833] select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 8000}) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  4833] select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 16000}) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  4833] select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 32000}) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  4833] select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 50000}) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  4833] select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 50000}) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  4833] select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 50000}) = 0 (Timeout)
```

It doesn't ever come back with information.  Other PGs do show the proper JSON data.
I tried to restart osd0, but not seeing any errors.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: what is the version of the ceph command line ? ceph pg X.X dump is not a valid hammer command, ceph pg X.X query is. It will help if you're running the same version client and server side.

Comment: Hello  You are of course right.  It is ceph pg 0.21 query.  That was my fault and I will edit this. I am using Hammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue! It was with pools which had no OSD after they were removed via crush rules.  I am not exactly sure why the PGs were created and rules just allowed the OSDs to be moved, but that is not material.

After I deleted all the empty pools I am fine now.

For those who want a procedure how to find that out:

First:

```
ceph health detail
```

To find which had issue, then:

```
ceph pg ls-by-pool
```

To match the pg with the pools. Afterwards delete the pool with:

```
ceph osd pool delete <pool name> <pool name> --yes-i-really-really-mean-it
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely to have a network configuration that does not allow some OSDs to talk to each other. The problem you have with `pg 0.21 dump` is probably the same issue.

Contrary to most `ceph` commands that communicate with the MON, `pg 0.21 dump` will try to [communicate directly with the OSD that hosts the pg](https://github.com/ceph/ceph/blob/firefly/src/osdc/Objecter.cc#L1488).

Since `ceph osd stat` returns that all OSDs are `up` and `in`, it means the communication between the MONs and the OSDs is not at fault.

Comment: Issue with this theory is that pg 0.21 is in fact on the same box as I am running ceph query from.  There are no iptables on this at all.  In Addition I am able to query PG 0.33 which would seem to me, to indicate that there are no issues with network communication at all.

Comment: I think you maybe on to something... Look at this 
pool 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
pool 1 1 0 0 0 0 678 1 1
pool 2 7 0 0 0 0 0 14 14
pool 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
pool 4 32 0 0 0 0 0 64 64
pool 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
pool 6 32074 0 0 0 0 134083171606 825527 825527
pool 7 20365 0 0 0 0 67625637348 1519593 1519593
 sum 52479 0 0 0 0 201708809632 2345199 2345199

I can query pg in the OSD6/7 NP.  I can't do so for others.  Doesn't it use port 6789? (only one I see in strace)

Comment: Now this is very interesting...
ceph pg scrub 0.21
Error EAGAIN: pg 0.21 has no primary osd

Comment: if you check the logs of the osd that you're trying to query, you will probably see that something is off

Comment: I did and I see nothing there at all.  Just to be sure I understand.  Shouldn't PG 0.21 be on OSD 0 by definition?  Is it possible that since I added and removed an older OSD that PG was "orphaned" and attached to a no longer existed OSD0? If so is there anyway to just delete these?

Comment: PG 0.21 is placement group 21 of the pool 0, it does not say which OSD is being used. PG transparently replace their OSD, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you Loic.  Knowing that would have given me answer far quicker.  I was under impression that 0 stood for OSD, but it makes far more sense that it is Pool.